Mi código hecho en Python me lee los datos de un archivo .txt en todas las opciones menos la segunda
Buenas tengo un problema con un menu de opciones, en la que el codigo lee los datos de un archivo .txt y por alguna razon en todas las opciones me lo lee excepto en la segunda y no logro entender por qué, no veo que es lo que me falta.
datos =open("Habitaciones.txt","r")
lista_habitaciones = [habitacion.split() for habitacion in datos]
def imprimir_habitaciones (lista_habitaciones):
    print("Nro. de Habitacion, Tipo, Precio por noche,estado, Cantidad de noches.")
    for habitacion in (lista_habitaciones):
        print (habitacion)

def cant_habitaciones_libres (lista_habitaciones):

    for habitacion in (lista_habitaciones) :
        if habitacion[3] =="libre":
            print ("La habitacion",habitacion[0],"Está disponible") 

def ganancia_individual (lista_habitaciones):

    for habitacion in (lista_habitaciones):
        if habitacion[4] !=0:
            precioxdias= int(habitacion[2]) * int(habitacion[4])
            print ("La habitacion",habitacion [0], "recauda", precioxdias,"por",habitacion[4],"dias.")
            
def ganancia_total (lista_habitaciones):
    contadorPrecio= 0
    for habitacion in (lista_habitaciones):
        if habitacion[3]== "ocupado" or "reservado":
            precioxdias= int(habitacion[2]) * int(habitacion[4])
            contadorPrecio= contadorPrecio + precioxdias
    total =print("La ganancia total es de",contadorPrecio)
    return total
         
    
opcion = (input("Elija una opcion \n 1)Consultar el estado de todas las habitaciones\n 2)Ver habitaciones disponibles \n 3)Calcular ganancia por habitacion \n 4)Suma total de ganancia \n 5)salir "))
while opcion != "5":
    if opcion =="1":
        print ("Ha elegido la opcion 1")
        imprimir_habitaciones(lista_habitaciones)
    
       
    elif opcion == "2":
        print ("Ha elegido la opcion 2")
        cant_habitaciones_libres(lista_habitaciones)

    elif opcion == "3":  
        print ("Ha elegido la opcion 3")
        ganancia_individual(lista_habitaciones)
    
    elif opcion == "4":
        print ("Ha elegido la opcion 4")
        ganancia =ganancia_total(lista_habitaciones)
    else:
    
        print("Opcion invalida intente de nuevo")
    
    opcion = input("Elija una opcion \n 1)Consultar el estado de todas las habitaciones\n 2)Ver habitaciones disponibles \n 3)Calcular ganancia total \n 4)Suma Total de ganancia \n 5)salir\n")


Al momento de ingresar la opción 2 solo me ejecuta el print que confirma que el usuario eligió la opción 2 pero no llama a la función. No me tira error ni nada.
Edito el contenido del archivo txt es el siguiente:
1 "individual" 80000  "ocupado" 3
2 "individual" 80000  "ocupado" 5
3 "individual" 80000  "libre" 0
4 "doble" 100000  "reservado" 2
5 "doble" 100000  "ocupado" 6
6 "doble" 100000  "libre" 0
7 "suite" 130000  "libre" 0
8 "suite" 130000  "reservado" 1

No veo porque deberia de mostrar algo... simplemente esta linea: if habitacion[3] =="libre": es falsa siempre... entonces no hay nada que hacer...

Ahi edite el post, agregue el contenido del archivo

En el estado (en el archivo) pusiste "libre", con comillas. El texto debe ir sin comillas.
Con está línea,
6 "doble" 100000 "libre" 0

el valor de habitaciones[3] es "libre" (7 caracteres), no libre (5 caracteres).
Elimina todas las comillas en el archivo de datos, de modo que las lineas se vean así:
6 doble 100000 libre 0


Perdón, el archivo esta dividido en líneas pero por alguna razón cuando lo copie aquí al foro se escribió todo seguido, ahí intente arreglarlo

@Andros esto no es un foro.. es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas ;)

Hola buenas si te funciona el código pero ha de poner libre con minúscula en el fichero Habitaciones.txt porque en python encuentra la diferencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas
Si quieres que lea las dos posibilidades pon un or en el metodo def cant_habitaciones_libres (lista_habitaciones):
for habitacion in (lista_habitaciones) :
    if habitacion[3] =="libre" or habitacion[3] =="Libre":
        print ("La habitacion",habitacion[0],"Está disponible") 


¿Y si escribe "LIBRE"? Para estos casos, lo más seguro es convertir el texto a minúsculas antes de comparar.
